# Pass Outlook.MailMessage to PowerShell script via Shell command

Tags: vba, powershell, outlook

I'm passing selected `Outlook.MailMessage` properties from a VBA script to PowerShell:

```
Public Sub InvokeMessageParser()

    For Each Item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then

            Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem: Set MailItem = Item

            // arrange
            Dim cmd As String: cmd = "powershell -NoExit -NoProfile -File C:\Users\[user]\Desktop\Invoke-MessageParser.ps1 -Subject """ & MailItem.Subject & """ -Verbose"

            // act
            i = Shell(cmd, vbNormalFocus)

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

`Invoke-MessageParser.ps1`:

```
param (
    [string]$Subject
)

Write-Host "Subject: $Subject"
```

Which prints the expected value to the console.

I would prefer to pass the entire message, but haven't been able to get the syntax correct:

```
// arrange
Dim cmd As String: cmd = "powershell -NoExit -NoProfile -File C:\Users\[user]\Desktop\Invoke-MessageParser.ps1 -Message " & MailItem
```

`Invoke-MessageParser.ps1`:

```
param (
    [object]$Message
)
Write-Verbose "Subject: $($Message.Subject)"
```

Which results in `Subject:` being printed to the console.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you debug your code? Do you run it in Visual Studio Code or PowerShell ISE?
That way you can easily see what members $Message have.

Comment: I'm using Outlook for the VBA part and VSCode for the PowerShell part.  `$Message` is a `System.String`.

Comment: craig wrote: *$Message is a System.String*. In that case there's no member **.subject**.Back to the drawing board

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass a string via a command line. You cannot pass a COM object. The best you can do is pass the value of the `MailItem.EntryID` property and use it to open the object by teh entry id in the child process using `Namespace.GetItemFromID`.